# Trying to create Conda environment via YAML results in PIP dependency conflicts and "Could not find a version" errors

Tags: pip, conda

For context, I'm currently using a MacBook to run a lot of machine learning experiments using the MPS backend. This means that when I install PyTorch, I can't download any of the stable version and must resort to the `2.1.0.dev` version. In addition to this, I currently use Python 3.10 and this is specified in my `environment.yml` file via:

```
  - python=3.10.11=h218abb5_2
```

but when I try to run `conda create env --file environment.yml` I get the following errors:

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.6.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.6.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.1.0.dev20230422 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.1.0.dev20230422

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

My questions are:

1. How is it that if my Python version is 3.10 those other packages that seem to require < 3.10 are running? And why the sudden conflicts when trying to create the Conda environment?
2. Is there any way that I can install PyTorch automatically via `conda create` rather than having to install a separate command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about PyPI, but at least for [PyTorch's nightly Conda builds](https://anaconda.org/pytorch-nightly/pytorch/files) the nightlies are removed daily (yes, terrible for reproduction). So, any exact specification, like `torch==2.1.0.dev20230422`, only works for a day or so (i.e., April 22-23, 2023). One option with Conda is to simply prioritize the `pytorch-nightly` channel, e.g., something like:

```
name: pytorch-dev
channels:
  - pytorch-nightly
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pytorch
  ## include additional dependencies
```

This would ensure that the latest development build of `pytorch` is used.

### Additional notes

I would strongly recommend taking proactive steps to package any such created environment for archival/reproduction purposes (e.g., with [`conda-pack`](https://github.com/conda/conda-pack)), since it cannot be exactly recreated otherwise. Note that tools like `conda-pack` require original tarballs and package caches to be intact in order to package the environment, so one should avoid running `conda clean -p` or `conda clean -t` before archiving.